# CSS selectors - group select

Tags: css

I have four elements like this:

```
<div class="hover-border top"></div>
<div class="hover-border right"></div>
<div class="hover-border bottom"></div>
<div class="hover-border left"></div>
```

Currently I do my CSS selection like this:

```
div.hover-border.right, div.hover-border.left {
    attribute: value
}

div.hover-border.top, div.hover-border.bottom {
    attribute: value
}
```

Is there anyway to use CSS selectors to do group select on one class? Can I do something like this, where the first class attribute "hover-border" must be matched and then it can match on either of the following classes in parentheses:

```
div.hover-border.(right, left) {
    attribute: value
}

div.hover-border.(top, bottom) {
    attribute: value
}
```

Thanks for your help. It is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the standard way to do this would be:

```
div.hover-border {
    attribute: value
}

div.hover-border.top, div.hover-border.bottom {
    attribute: value
}
```

The specificity of the second rules overrides the 'default' first rules

Comment: Yep. I am already doing it that way now :-) Hoped there would be some other way to do it without using SASS or LESS.

But thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

> div.hover-border.left

this is not the right way to use selectors. there's a big difference between "body.class" and "body .class".

please read this article:
http://css-tricks.com/whats-the-difference/

regarding your question, there is a way to use group selectors - SASS or at least LESS. but then, it comes with a series of problems :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use CSS Frameworks like `SASS`, `LESS`, etc. Also `Emmet`. They are good for mixing selectors.